# No data being displayed in view in DropDownListFor using basic MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am relatively new to MVC. I am working on some a project to get a basic understanding of how the MVC architecture works, but am having some issues. I think I have most of it covered but something (small I hope) is missing.

Below is my model, the controller/DataAccess and BusinessLogic class functions I have written, and my method of displaying on the view.

Can someone please glaze through this and hopefully spot what I am either doing wrong or missing? Thank you.

@edit: Also would like to add I have debuggers in my controller func, BL and DA functions and NONE of them are ever even getting hit... I believe this is the issue. Also big thanks to whoever beautified my question.

#### Model

```cs
public class TerminalCommandVM
{
    public TerminalCommandVM()
    {
        TerminalsDDL = new List<SelectListItem>();
        TerminalCommandLookupsDDL = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public TerminalCommand TerminalCommand { get; set; }

    public List<TerminalCommand> TerminalCommands { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Terminal ID")]
    public List<SelectListItem> TerminalsDDL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Command")]
    public List<SelectListItem> TerminalCommandLookupsDDL { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
//GET: Terminals
public ActionResult GetTerminals()
{
    var model = TCBL.GetTerminalDropDowns();
    return View(model);
}
```

#### Business Logic function

```cs
public TerminalCommandVM GetTerminalDropDowns()
{
    TerminalCommandVM ternimals = new TerminalCommandVM();
    ternimals.TerminalsDDL = TCDA.GetTerminalsDropDown();

    return ternimals;
}
```

#### Data Access function

```cs
public List<SelectListItem> GetTerminalsDropDown()
{
    var terminals = DB.TerminalCommand.Select(o => 
        new SelectListItem { Text = o.TerminalID, Value = o.TerminalID})
        .ToList();

    return terminals;
}
```

#### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetTerminals", "TerminalCommand", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formTerminalCommand" }))
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Terminal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL, new { Class = "form-control" })
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">HelpDescription</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also going to include my layout for when this page gets hit:

```
                    <li class="sidenav-item@(currentPage == "TerminalCommand/Index" ? " active" : "")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "TerminalCommand")" class="sidenav-link"><div>Terminal Commands</div></a>
                </li>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but you are using the wrong property name for the anonymous object being passed to `DropDownListFor()` as the `htmlAttributes` argument. So change this `new { Class = "form-control" }` to this `new { @class = "form-control" }`.

Comment: Another thing that jumps out at me is that you are returning a `List<SelectListItem>` from `GetTerminalsDropDown()`. By doing so, you are tightly-coupling your DAL to the UI layer. I would recommend instead returning a common data structure (like a `Dictionary<int, string>`) from the DAL and then do the mapping to the `SelectListItem`s in the view. That way later you can re-use the DAL method even if it's not going to be used in a `List<SelectListItem>` in a different part of the application.

Comment: Ok thank you @LewsTherin I will try this out and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

If the break point in your controller method isn't getting hit, then it may be an issue with redirects, routes, url, etc. There's a lot of things you can do to trouble shoot this issue, but nothing concrete.

1. Do you have any of the built in controllers that come with an empty project (Home, About, etc)? If so, do those work?
2. Add a constructor method to the controller and set a break point within. If it hits, then the issue may be with action.
3. If you haven't made any changes to the route config or used the route attribute, the url should be http://localhost:xxxxx/{ControllerName}/GetTerminals

Comment: 1) Yes these work 2) Yes, hits constructor but never gets to my method. 3) Yes this is done

Comment: Have you tried just adding an Index method and an Index view to see that succeeds?

Comment: None.. however I figured out the problem. I was replacing an old view (previously called Create.cshtml) with my Index.html.... I changed the old views name to CreateOLD.html and changed Index to Create.cshtml and this fixed everything...